# how to rotate square clockwise and anticlockwise on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

square rotates on mouseover in clockwise direction for odd numbered mouseover and anticlockwise direction for even numbered mouseover

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box")

function rotate() {
  //if ( ? ? ? ) {
  //  box.className = 'even';
  //} else {
  //  box.className = 'odd';
  //}
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.even {
  transform: rotate( -180deg);
  /* transition: transform 150ms ease; */
}

.odd {
  transform: rotate( 180deg);
  /* transition: transform 150ms ease; */
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onmouseover="rotate()"></div>
```

Comment: Hi You seem to have forgot to post your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this only in css if you need . below is the code.

```css
.cmn{
 display:inline-block;
  padding:65px;
  background:red;
  margin:45px;

  color:#fff;
}


.even {
    transform: rotate( 0deg );            
    transition: transform 150ms ease;  /**/
}
.even:hover {
    transform: rotate( -180deg );            
    transition: transform 150ms ease;  /**/
}


.odd {
    transform: rotate( 0deg );            
    transition: transform 150ms ease; 
}
.odd:hover {
    transform: rotate( 180deg );            
     transition: transform 150ms ease; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="cmn even">Lorem Even</div>
  <div class="cmn odd">Epsum Odd</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use pure css like i do on the code below**
Why you use even and odd without having an element in HTML?
You dont need javascript for rotating an element

```css
#box {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
transition: transform 1s;
}

#box:hover { /*here is the change*/
    transform: rotate( -180deg );            
    /* transition: transform 150ms ease; */
}

#box:hover { /*here is the change*/
    transform: rotate( 180deg );            
    /* transition: transform 150ms ease; */
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const box = document.getElementById('box')
var isOdd = true;
function rotate(){
    if(isOdd === true){
        box.className = "odd"
        
    } else if (isOdd === false){
        box.className = "even"
    }
    isOdd = !isOdd;
}

#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: transform 2s;
}
.odd{
    transform: rotate(180deg) ;
} 
.even{
    transform: rotate(0) ;
}

<div  onmouseover="rotate()" id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).